# Save query string data using rest framework in Django

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I need to save to a database the query string data coming from a GET request using Django Rest framework.

Something like this:

URL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/snippets/?longitude=123123&latitude=456456"

```
class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    #code here for saving the query string data to database, in this case save: 
    #{
    #"longitude":123123,
    #"latitude":456456
    #}
```

It's just like saving the params data like it were a POST request.

Comment: You should not do that: A GET request should *not* have side-effects per specs of the HTTP protocol.

Comment: see https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/a-get-request-with-side-effects.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to save to a database the query string data coming from a GET request using Django Rest framework.

This is against the specifications of the HTTP protocol. Indeed, a GET request should only be used to *retrieve* data, not update data. For that a POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE request should be used. The querystring is normally used to *filter*, not to store data.

If you really want to do this, you can override the `.get(…)` handler and

```
# Warning: against the HTTP protocol specifications!
class SnippetCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    # {
    # "longitude":123123,
    # "latitude":456456
    # }
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.query_params)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(
            serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers
        )
```

But this is really *not* a good idea.

Comment: For some reason the App I am using: https://gpslogger.app/, send a get request to send the gps data: https://myserver.com/log?lat=%LAT&long=%LON... I need to save that data to a database. What do you think of this? By the way your solution worked good, thanks!